# Create mysql table using another table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a lookup table that contains 2 columns k_id, keywords as follow

```
k_id | keywords
  1  | hi
  2  | play
```

and so on

I want to create another table using the previous lookup table where I want to put the k_id values as the columns of the other table which it has id attribute only. this is the format

```
id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

and so on.
Is it possible to create such table? 
I am working on Java using mysql.

Please help

Comment: So you want to create a new table whos columns are named by the calues of col k-

Comment: can you do this strictly using SQL?  In some jedi world maybe so.   for us remaining use jdbc to read in the values you want then issue multiple jdbc calls to create the table then populate it

Comment: @Totoro yes that what i want. I cant get your point.

Comment: rather than do the table translation entirely in SQL I think you should read the data you want out of table 1 jdbc/java, then manipulate the data in java, then issue a series of sql/jdbc commands from java creating table 2.